# Gradle task dependsOn does not work

Tags: gradle

I want to setup simple dependency between tasks.

My `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task('Second', dependsOn: 'First') {
    println "Second"
}

task('First') {
    println "First"
}
```

As a result I expect `First` and than `Second`.
But I've got:

```
$ gradle build
Second
First
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 14):

Still the same error.. You're at **configuration** phase. Add actions to task and everything will be fine. This will work:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task('Second', dependsOn: 'First') << {
    println "Second"
}

task('First') << {
    println "First"
}
```

This is a configuration phase:

```groovy
task t1 {
   println "t1"
}
```

Code in configuration phase is executed before action. Adding action is done with `<<` (leftShift) operator.

```groovy
task t1 << {
   println "t1"
}
```

[Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N101A5) are the docs.

`<<` is just overridden operator do `doLast` method. Without it it will be:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task('Second', dependsOn: 'First') {
   doLast {
      println "Second"
   }
}

task('First') {
   doLast {
      println "First"
   }
}
```

I also encourage you to read [this](https://blog.softwaremill.com/my-task-whats-wrong-with-your-gradle-task-82312100c595) blog post.

Comment: I recommend to always use `doLast` instead of `<<`. The former allows to combine configuration and adding of task actions, and is much less error-prone.